# How to Authenticate my login page using OpenID Connect in android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have gone through many links to authenticate login page using OpenID Connect.
I can't understand how to do that.
I have to use openid connect to authenticate my login page in android.
Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Thank you in advance.